# Django annotate existance in related field

Tags: django, django-annotate

My models:

```
class Character(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Equipment(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Character, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete = models.RESTRICT)
```

And now i need to annotate if items are in equipment:

```
 you = Character.objects.get(pk=1)
 items = Item.objects.all().annotate(ready=Value(True, output_field=models.BooleanField()), filter=Q(equipment__owner__in=you))
```

but something is wrong :

```
TypeError: 'Character' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to annotate and have this `filter=Q(equipment__owner__in=you)`. The problem is `you` is an instance of `Character` not an iterable of characters so it should be `filter=Q(equipment__owner=you)`. Still this is incorrect as you cannot filter inside an annotation this way.

To annotate the existence of a related field use [Exists() subqueries [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries):

```py
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

you = Character.objects.get(pk=1)
equipments = Equipment.objects.filter(item=OuterRef('pk'), owner=you)
Item.objects.annotate(ready=Exists(equipments))
```

Comment: @Abdul_Aziz_Barkat I don't like it, but it works. :)